# Decode Opus-48 using Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, opus

I want to capture and decode VoIP conversation using Opus-48 codecs. I am using Wireshark to capture packets. Are there any free decoders available online ?? Wireshark doesn't save two way conversation as it works for other encoding schemes like G-729.

Answer (score 2):

Decode opus RTP pcap using python script here https://github.com/kamanashisroy/opus_stream_tool

Once we have the pcap, we can select an UDP packet in the stream and filter that out either by `udp.srcport`/`udp.dstport` or by `rtp.ssrc`.

Now, we can convert the pcap file into a hex-dump.

```
tshark -x -r in.pcap -Y "udp.srcport == myport" | cut -d " " -f 1-20 > tmp.txt
```

Finally we can use the *hex_to_opus* tool to record ogg encoded opus file.

```
hex_to_opus.py -x tmp.txt --recordfile out.opus --rtpoffset 42
```

Normally if it is IPv4 the rtp-offset is 42. Please find the start of the udp payload from the wireshark description of the packet.

Comment: Works great! please note that `hex_to_opus.py` assumes the Opus payload type is 111, though Opus is a dynamic PT and if your session uses another PT number, you won't be able to read it. Fortunately there's a `--payloadtype` option where you can specify the PT for your session (common values I've seen are 107 and 120, but its easy to find out with wireshark).

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices. Either use the libopus library directly, or else convert your RTP packets into an Ogg Opus files, and then use any player that supports Opus (Firefox, Chrome, VLC, ...) to play the Ogg file. In all cases, you should start at http://opus-codec.org/

Comment: any idea how o convert rtp packets into ogg opus files. Tried to use opus tools, but it doesnt seem to have tool for this.